# Flask redirect() sends invalid host

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I'm pulling out an old Flask application and trying to get it to run. However, `flask.redirect()` gives me some headache. This used to work before, maybe something changed in the recent Flask versions?

When I visit the application index page (`/`), it should redirect me to `/login` due to the `requires_auth()` decorator on the index view (see below). It actuall does redirect me, but the host is incorrect. Instead of ending up at `flux.example.com/login`, I end up at `flux/login`.

```
def requires_auth(func):
  ''' Decorator for view functions that require basic authentication. '''

  from .models import Session, User

  @functools.wraps(func)
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    app.logger.warn('Checking authentication ..')  # added for debug purposes just now
    app.logger.warn('Note: url_for(\'login\'): {}'.format(url_for('login')))
    user_name = session.get('user_name')
    user_passhash = session.get('user_passhash')
    with Session() as db_session:
      user = User.get_by(db_session, user_name, user_passhash)
      if not user:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    request.user = user
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  return wrapper
```

This is the response header:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:219
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 19 Apr 2017 21:18:51 GMT
Location:http://flux/login
Server:nginx/1.6.2
```

Setting `SERVER_NAME=https://flux.example.com` in the configuration didn't work. Actually, the whole app didn't work anymore, any page I visited I got 404.

How can I fix this redirect issue?

Python 3.6, Flask 0.10.1

Comment: I'm wondering where its getting the `http://flux` from at all if you didn't have a server_name before. If you search the codebase is the word flux specified anywhere?

Comment: @davidejones I think the only place where it could have snatched up that string was `app = Flask(__name__)` since `__name__ == 'flask'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were on the right track, but you should use just the hostname without the protocol: `SERVER_NAME=flux.example.com`.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same behaviour as with the scheme included. What does this change exactly? My app is hidden behind an NGinx proxy as `prox_pass http://localhost:5001$request_uri;`, maybe that is causing some issue? I tried adding [these](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache/#nginx) in case Flask checks the `Host` header but that didn't change it either.

Comment: Hm nevermind, using `prox_set_header Host $host;` worked!

Comment: Glad that you found a solution, proxies sometimes require special handling: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#deploying-proxy-setups